# How to define the constructor for a class that extends Date?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, constructor-overloading

How can I correctly define the constructor for a child-class of Date (typescript 4.1.3)?

The constructor definition of the Date object is this:

```
new(): Date;
new(value: number | string): Date;
new(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date;
```

in my code, I try to specify this:

```
class MyDate extends Date {
    // overloads copied from DateConstructor
    constructor();
    constructor(value: number | string);
    constructor(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number);
    // constructor impl
    constructor(
        yearOrValue?: number | string, month?: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number
    ) {
        super(yearOrValue, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms);
        /*    ^^^^^^^^^^^
              Argument of type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
              Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
         */         
    }
}
```

but this causes a compile error in the super call:

```
Argument of type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
```

How can I define the constructor parameters, so that I can call super with all possibilities that the original Date object has and keep type-safety (as much as possible)?

Notes:

- Here is a link to the [typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeARMAXAptNAPdA7AJjMutAN4BQ0VA9NdAPYBuaATiPWIdMPQA4CWafNABmLegFtoxNAGF6uCChYBXYCnotKVbgqWr1mgBQBKANzaqPRcrUaWRxmBAq0ALmi4VEgEatoAD7Q%20vy4AObmlro2BvZG8GhgLB5evqwANNASCigAFinefiyZ%20KhoAPwFacXQufQqLBCVnoUZWaEq6E1VRZkQaNaEzam9Wd0t1ZE60LTR%20naa0PwSvCBR1vOGDlHTCUkA8iwAas6uw60sgcHKoWGZ2bh559UlZc%20jdQ3jI20SHV3vNr9QbfC73UHVKImMg7HQQFS8VjxRIsQ4nFxoe45XKvdCZT6Ne7-NAQPoDBSEcFTaY6agAKmmAD1mSzWYzYTSdABBFhhbxoR4METQFDwRHQADkIXCVx%20lyCKgIaBEoSEEqWMFw9BQ0EgEH4YVwYB8IAwGmgvCSYAkaHQl3owtF4olcolADoOZzoAAVMUYCWK-DK1X4dX8TXa3VQA1Gk1m%20giv2S11uowAJgAzAAWACsJk90DpdC90CiAF9yGWgA)
- This is just some test-code, in the production version I have more code in the constructor
- I want a solution that works with a class (i.e. no messing with the prototype, etc.)

Comment: Screw it: `@ts-ignore constructor(...args) { super(...args) }`.

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah. That's also a perfectly reasonable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to support all of the signatures that `Date` supports,¹ I don't think you have much choice other than branching (or [punting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65795946/how-to-define-the-constructor-for-a-class-that-extends-date/65796063#comment116331756_65795946)):

```typescript
class MyDate extends Date {
    // overloads copied from DateConstructor
    constructor();
    constructor(value: number | string);
    constructor(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number);
    // constructor impl
    constructor(
        yearOrValue?: number | string,
        month?: number,
        date?: number,
        hours?: number,
        minutes?: number,
        seconds?: number,
        ms?: number
    ) {
        if (typeof yearOrValue === "undefined") {
            super();
        } else if (typeof month === "undefined") {
            super(yearOrValue);
        } else {
            // consider an assertion here that `yearOrValue` is a number
            super(yearOrValue as number, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeARMAXAptNAPdA7AJjMutAN4BQ0V0A9DdAPYBuaATiA2IdMAwA4BLNPmgAzVgwC20YmgDCDXBBSsArsBQNWlaryUr1m1gAoAlAG4dVPcrUatxpmBCq0ALmi5VkgEZtoAD7QtgK4AOYWVjyKtoYO8GhgrB5evmwANNCSiigAFinefqyZ+KhoAPwFacXQuQyqrBCVnoUZWaGq6E1VRZkQaHqEzam9Wd0t1ZHUtPQ2Bvas0AKSfCBRc3ZGxlHTCUkA8qwAas6uw62LQSHh6TvU2bh559W309Ol6M+9d1R1DeMjDI-dpeLpfIFvaj9QYAi6vSFjcHaaamMjAgSiaDGFDwPhoBiYvasQ4nFwYAC8lOgACJVAQ0KJQsJqaiKAi3hBVHiTFMEQBfTAgfpLTHY3H4zEPPLQSnkml0-AMpn4Flo9nTTnc4xEkmnNC8yECtBCjBs9VUOjRJQCRWLMC4aCQfqsFACRS1NgYPKoaAAAx1xz1vqWMDAEyKwI1XLY2sSxMDZMdMEBNSluRKZUyf0amUkHS6fQGikIuYgBrefKilcrQA)

---

¹ *(For what it's worth, I don't think you* have *to, though you may well want to. Unlike `Array` or `Promise`, I don't think the `Date` constructor is called anywhere in the standard library)*

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some check and call the proper parent constructor for each situation:

```
constructor(
        yearOrValue?: number | string, month?: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number
    ) {
        if (yearOrValue === undefined) {
            super()
        } else if (month === undefined) {
            super(yearOrValue)
        } else if (typeof yearOrValue === 'number') {
            super(yearOrValue, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, ms)
        }
    }
```

[Working playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: If you're suggesting mimicking how the Date constructor processes arguments, then you should follow the [pattern in ECMA-262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date). That would mean firstly counting the number of arguments, otherwise `new MyDate(2021, undefined)` in the "subclass" will behave differently to the Date constructor given the same values. Also, the values passed to the Date constructor can all be strings or numbers. The first argument can also be an object (e.g. a Date instance).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this today:

```
class MyDate extends Date {
  constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Date>) {
    super(...args)
  }
}
```